# Export Podio items

Tags: php, podio

I'm trying to export an XLSX from Podio but I get the following error:

```
The app with id 11111 does not have the right export on app with id 11111
```

Ofcourse these are fake ID's but in the error message both ID's are the same. This is my code:

```
$client_id = "id";
$client_secret = "secret";

Podio::setup($client_id, $client_secret);

$leads_app_id = 11111;
$lead_app_token = "token";

//Auth with "Leads" app
Podio::authenticate_with_app($leads_app_id, $lead_app_token);

// $leads_auth = Podio::$oauth;

$leads_export = PodioItem::export( $leads_app_id, 'xlsx', array() );

file_put_contents("../test.xlsx", $leads_export);
```

Could anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `PodioItem::export` api call you have to **authenticate as a Podio user**.
It won't work if you authenticate with the app itself.